# How can we know if struct is on CPU cache or lost them to memory cache?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, cpu-cache

I'm trying to write C# game framework, So performance was critical here.

Here is the [reference](https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/3860) I've found.

Question is, How can we know if structs are still on the CPU-cache?

If we can't, Then what scenarios pushing structs to memory-cache.

For example, Push a struct to List<> then access them later, Will it still be on CPU-cache?

Comment: Generally, what causes something to be evicted from the cache is something else wanting/needing to go into that same cache line, i.e. typically another thread pushes out your cached value.

Comment: The answer to everything in this question is "it depends".

Comment: Not everything you develop for a game is "performance-critical". In fact you may even lose far more time by over-optimizing your code than you gain by it. For example if you hunt for some faster code that is ever executed only a single time per app will you really care for 1nano-sec?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I know this should rely on semantic rather than performance. But this is a server side program and I need to handle the very high amount of users and game loop.

Comment: First of all if you had anything to optimize you would come to us with benchmarks.

Comment: Have a look at this detailed paper on the subject: https://lwn.net/Articles/250967/. Also, have a look at this related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8126311/2557263.

Comment: That blog is naive. Yes structs use less memory but they have significant overheads when being passed around. It'd probably be a bad idea to replace a class with a struct for 99% of scenarios. Memory allocation is rarely the bottle neck in application.

Comment: @Liam I'm not going to replace everything but critical looping part :)

Comment: @Liam Structs don't use less memory as a general rule.  When used to solve certain problems, they can use less memory than classes, or potentially use memory that's cheaper to deallocate.  But only when in the very specific situations in which they were designed to come out ahead.  They can easily use more memory, or use memory that's more costly, when used to solve a problem they weren't designed to solve effectively.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing @Servy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can we know if structs are still on the CPU-cache?

No, no need to know.

> If we can't, Then what scenarios pushing structs to memory-cache.

It will exactly be there on processing it, but would be disposed after it.

> Push a struct to List<> then access them later, Will it still be on CPU-cache?

`Push a struct to List<>` is a memory operation, CPU will do the `push` operation, but probably it does not need to load it at all, it can just change the `pointer` only. but data will be `partially` or `sequentially` loaded to CPU-cache exactly if CPU NEED those data later.

To optimize cache performance by SOFTWARE, it's called [Cache-Conscious Data Structure](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ccds.pdf), to make [Pointer Based Data Structures Cache Conscious](ftp://ftp.cs.wisc.edu/wwt/computer00_conscious.pdf), which would improve performance greatly. I did a test around 15 years ago with C, which improve performance so much, around 70+% more, but I lost those code now.

You have to be professional on using performance tools first:

1. [Visual studio performance tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/overviews-performance-tools?view=vs-2017) provide you general ways to identify which part of code is consuming performance in any level.
2. this post [Value Types vs Reference Types](https://adamsitnik.com/Value-Types-vs-Reference-Types/) provides an great example on [Benchmark Runner](https://adamsitnik.com/Value-Types-vs-Reference-Types/)

it's impossible to implement a framework that could feed all proposes, just like the [example](https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/3860) what your referenced, it's case-by-case. I think you can put a context, then we continue discussing on it.

CPU cache is pretty smaller, compared to memory, its units load needed data only, then dispose it immediately after processing, then load next data in next memory address if its there, but reference type could store NEXT data somewhere else, but not NEXT location, which will lower performance to locate it.That's why 3-level caches appear, the 3rd cache will try to locate data for 2nd, then 1st will use it from a faster cache.

`List<T>` is an reference type, which will host an instance in different memory blocks of a `heap`, then make performance a bit worse, but value type objects use `stack`, which could stay data together, then CPU could load them faster, but you have to specify operations to improve your case as well, it's not always generic in any real project.

Actually, to improve performance, `LINQ` translates many kinds of objects to value type `structure`, instead keeping use `class` itself.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all answers to your question is it depends, you can however see if something is in CPU cache by debugging the process and monitoring *"Debug -> Windows -> Registers"* where you can see which memory address is loaded into every register and stepping through code you can see what something goes out and in. That's as far as I can go.

I would suggest you use [benchmarking](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) for micro optimizations and only after that start digging for lower details.